# Carthage ld: warning: directory not found for option ' empty search path

Tags: swift, xcode7, carthage, xcglogger

im trying to use carthage with a brand new empty project 
and adding two dependency to Cartfile
here how it looks like:

```
github "RestKit/RestKit" == 0.25.0
github "DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger"
```

next im going a :

```
carthage update --platform ios
```

and get the following error after building a XCGLogger:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

i've tried to delete and add different search paths with no luck :(